# php artisan key:generate doesn't do anything

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I tried previous questions and answers before in SO, but nothing solves my problem.

1. I clone a new project in my Mac. Then `composer update`.
2. Everything is ok so far. But when i manually create `.env` file via `touch .env`
3. and type `php artisan key:generate`. Nothing happens. Absolutely nothing. No error and .env is blank as it was before. I had the same error. I tried applying `sudo`, nothing happens. 
   It just says:
   `Application key set successfully.`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Copy the .env.example file and rename it to .env then try

Comment: it solves the problem! why is that? can you explain? i think you should reply this as an answer so that I an also give you a little feedback :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Touhidul Islam You have to copy `.env.example` file and rename it to `.env` then run  `php artisan key:generate` command

Comment: It works only if any variable set in `.env` file like `APP_KEY`, suppose you are creating .env file manually and write `APP_KEY=` then run `php artisan key:generate` command it will work, in your case your `.env` file is blank, i would suggest you to copy `.env.example` file and rename it to `.env` then work on it.